# How to select rows in a DataFrame between two values

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I am trying to modify a DataFrame `df` to only contain rows for which the values in the column `closing_price` are between 99 and 101 and trying to do this with the code below.

However, I get the error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

and I am wondering if there is a way to do this without using loops.

```
df = df[99 <= df['closing_price'] <= 101]
```

Comment: The issue here is that you can't compare a scalar with an array hence the error, for comparisons you have to use the bitwise operators and enclose them in parentheses due to operator precedence

Comment: `df.query` and `pd.eval` seem like good fits for this use case. For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Comment: @Ed *"you can't compare a scalar with an array"* - Sure you can; `df['closing_price'] <= 101` will work just fine. That's not the problem here; the actual problem is that under the hood, `x <= s <= y` is handled as `x <= s and s <= y`, and the `and` causes the error for Pandas. Secondly, there's no equivalent using bitwise operators that doesn't require writing out `s` twice; instead, use `Series.between`.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You should use `()` to group your boolean vector to remove ambiguity.

```
df = df[(df['closing_price'] >= 99) & (df['closing_price'] <= 101)]
```

Answer (score 350):

Consider [Series.between](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df = df[df['closing_price'].between(99, 101)]
```

Comment: Is there "not between" functionality in pandas? I am not finding it.

Comment: @dsugasa, use the [tilde operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46054318/1422451) with `between`.

Comment: @dsugasa e.g. `df = df[~df['closing_price'].between(99, 101)]`

Answer (score 37):

there is a nicer alternative - use [query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#the-query-method) method:

```
In [58]: df = pd.DataFrame({'closing_price': np.random.randint(95, 105, 10)})

In [59]: df
Out[59]:
   closing_price
0            104
1             99
2             98
3             95
4            103
5            101
6            101
7             99
8             95
9             96

In [60]: df.query('99 <= closing_price <= 101')
Out[60]:
   closing_price
1             99
5            101
6            101
7             99
```

**UPDATE:** answering the comment *(edited to fix minor mistakes)*:

> I like the syntax here but fell down when trying to combine with
> expression:
>
> ```
> df.query('(mean - 2*sd) <= closing_price <= (mean + 2*sd)')
> ```

My data is all within 2 standard deviations of the mean, so I'll do 1 instead to demonstrate:

```
In [161]: qry = ("(closing_price.mean() - closing_price.std())" +
     ...:        " <= closing_price <= " +
     ...:        "(closing_price.mean() + closing_price.std())")
     ...:

In [162]: df.query(qry)
Out[162]:
   closing_price
1             99
2             98
5            101
6            101
7             99
9             96
```

or

```
In [163]: mean = df['closing_price'].mean()
     ...: sd = df['closing_price'].std()
     ...: df.query('(@mean - @sd) <= closing_price <= (@mean + @sd)')
     ...:
Out [163]:
   closing_price
1             99
2             98
5            101
6            101
7             99
9             96
```

Comment: I like the syntax here but fell down when trying to combine with expresison; df.query('(mean + 2 *sd) <= closing_price <=(mean + 2 *sd)')

Comment: @mappingdom, what is `mean` and `sd`? Are those column names?

Comment: no they are the calculated mean and standard deviation stored as a float

Comment: @mappingdom, what you mean saying "stored"?

Comment: @mappingdom, i've updated my post - is that what you were asking for?

Comment: This way doesn't work if we have a name like 'A name full of spaces spaces'.

Comment: @MaiHai, it does if you use it [correctly](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508)

Comment: Is there a possibility where we could use `.between()` within `.query()` ?? I really would love to know that.

Comment: @ManojKumar, give it a try)

Comment: @MaxU - it threw an error when I tired `df.query('closing_price.between(99, 101, inclusive=True)')`

Comment: @ManojKumar, `df.query('closing_price.between(99, 101, inclusive=True)', engine="python")` - but this will be slower compared to "numexpr" engine.

Comment: @MaxU - Aaawww! I forgot engine... thanks for this :)

Comment: @mappingdom There seem to be easier ways to [Detect and exclude outliers in a pandas DataFrame](/q/23199796/4518341)

Answer (score 12):

```
newdf = df.query('closing_price.mean() <= closing_price <= closing_price.std()')
```

or

```
mean = closing_price.mean()
std = closing_price.std()

newdf = df.query('@mean <= closing_price <= @std')
```

Comment: What do `closing_price.mean()` and `closing_price.std()` have to do with the question? And what does that mean, anyway, `mean <= data <= std`? I'm not a stats expert myself. Maybe you meant something like `(mean - 2*sd) <= data <= (mean + 2*sd)` as in [MaxU's answer](/a/38889524/4518341)? (Which, coincidentally, I just added the `@` syntax to.)

Answer (score 6):

If one has to call [`pd.Series.between(l,r)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) **repeatedly** (for different bounds `l` and `r`), a lot of work is repeated unnecessarily. In this case, it's beneficial to sort the frame/series once and then use [`pd.Series.searchsorted()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html). I measured a speedup of up to 25x, see below.

```
def between_indices(x, lower, upper, inclusive=True):
    """
    Returns smallest and largest index i for which holds 
    lower <= x[i] <= upper, under the assumption that x is sorted.
    """
    i = x.searchsorted(lower, side="left" if inclusive else "right")
    j = x.searchsorted(upper, side="right" if inclusive else "left")
    return i, j

# Sort x once before repeated calls of between()
x = x.sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
# x = x.sort_values(ignore_index=True) # for pandas>=1.0
ret1 = between_indices(x, lower=0.1, upper=0.9)
ret2 = between_indices(x, lower=0.2, upper=0.8)
ret3 = ...
```

---

**Benchmark**

Measure repeated evaluations (`n_reps=100`) of `pd.Series.between()` as well as the method based on `pd.Series.searchsorted()`, for different arguments `lower` and `upper`. On my MacBook Pro 2015 with Python v3.8.0 and Pandas v1.0.3, the below code results in the following outpu

```
# pd.Series.searchsorted()
# 5.87 ms ± 321 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# pd.Series.between(lower, upper)
# 155 ms ± 6.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# Logical expressions: (x>=lower) & (x<=upper)
# 153 ms ± 3.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def between_indices(x, lower, upper, inclusive=True):
    # Assumption: x is sorted.
    i = x.searchsorted(lower, side="left" if inclusive else "right")
    j = x.searchsorted(upper, side="right" if inclusive else "left")
    return i, j

def between_fast(x, lower, upper, inclusive=True):
    """
    Equivalent to pd.Series.between() under the assumption that x is sorted.
    """
    i, j = between_indices(x, lower, upper, inclusive)
    if True:
        return x.iloc[i:j]
    else:
        # Mask creation is slow.
        mask = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=bool)
        mask[i:j] = True
        mask = pd.Series(mask, index=x.index)
        return x[mask]

def between(x, lower, upper, inclusive=True):
    mask = x.between(lower, upper, inclusive=inclusive)
    return x[mask]

def between_expr(x, lower, upper, inclusive=True):
    if inclusive:
        mask = (x>=lower) & (x<=upper)
    else:
        mask = (x>lower) & (x<upper)
    return x[mask]

def benchmark(func, x, lowers, uppers):
    for l,u in zip(lowers, uppers):
        func(x,lower=l,upper=u)

n_samples = 1000
n_reps = 100
x = pd.Series(np.random.randn(n_samples))
# Sort the Series.
# For pandas>=1.0:
# x = x.sort_values(ignore_index=True)
x = x.sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)

# Assert equivalence of different methods.
assert(between_fast(x, 0, 1, True ).equals(between(x, 0, 1, True)))
assert(between_expr(x, 0, 1, True ).equals(between(x, 0, 1, True)))
assert(between_fast(x, 0, 1, False).equals(between(x, 0, 1, False)))
assert(between_expr(x, 0, 1, False).equals(between(x, 0, 1, False)))

# Benchmark repeated evaluations of between().
uppers = np.linspace(0, 3, n_reps)
lowers = -uppers
%timeit benchmark(between_fast, x, lowers, uppers)
%timeit benchmark(between, x, lowers, uppers)
%timeit benchmark(between_expr, x, lowers, uppers)
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of this

```
df = df[99 <= df['closing_price'] <= 101]
```

You should use this

```
df = df[(99 <= df['closing_price']) & (df['closing_price'] <= 101)]
```

We have to use NumPy's bitwise logic operators `|`, `&`, `~`, `^` for compounding queries.
Also, the parentheses are important for operator precedence.

For more info, you can visit the link: [Comparisons, Masks, and Boolean Logic](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.06-boolean-arrays-and-masks.html) (excerpt from the Python Data Science Handbook by Jake VanderPlas).

Answer (score 5):

If you're dealing with multiple values and multiple inputs you could also set up an apply function like this. In this case filtering a dataframe for GPS locations that fall withing certain ranges.

```
def filter_values(lat,lon):
    if abs(lat - 33.77) < .01 and abs(lon - -118.16) < .01:
        return True
    elif abs(lat - 37.79) < .01 and abs(lon - -122.39) < .01:
        return True
    else:
        return False


df = df[df.apply(lambda x: filter_values(x['lat'],x['lon']),axis=1)]
```

Comment: Should point out that `.apply` is ideally a last resort since it's so much slower. See [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](/q/16476924/4518341). Instead you could use a vectorized option, like say: `from functools import reduce; from operator import or_; cs = [(33.77, -118.16), (37.79, -122.39)]; df[reduce(or_, (df[['lat', 'lon']].sub(c).abs().lt(.01).all(axis=1) for c in cs))]`. (I made some other changes here too, like making it DRY.) Admittedly this code is pretty "sludgy", but it should be fast, and there are ways to write it that are more readable.