# Searching through data frame columns in type string (containing numeric range), with user inputs that are in type float

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, types

Trying to only use python installed libraries and pandas library because I am a complete novice. I am wrapping up a 6 week python foundations course.

For a final project, I am making a plant buying guide. Based on a series of questions I am asking the user, I am parsing out a data frame containing 60 entries. To give you an idea, the first section of my question created a filtered data frame using this code

```
care_df = df.loc[
    lambda x:
    (x['sunlight'].str.lower().str.contains(user_sunlight_pref.lower()))
    & (x['watering_levels'].str.lower().str.contains(user_water_pref.lower()))
    & (x['humidity_preference'].str.lower().str.contains(user_humidity_pref.lower()))
    ]
```

where user_sunlight_pref stored user input (ie maybe they chose 'Indirect light' as their sunlight preference).

NOW, I am on my second section of questions where I begin to ask about height and spread. The data frame columns I will be searching for have this format of entry: '1.00 to 2.00 feet'.

MY QUESTION/PROBLEM: For the user questions, I've tried to make descriptive ranges that I present to the user as possible options that they submit as their input:

```
"Desk range- plants that are appropriate for desks and surfaces, like short bookshelves or corner areas."
" These plants will not block eyesight."
```

On the back end, I want to create a numeric range, like 'desk range' = anything between 0.25 to 1.50,that I could then use to search through my data frame. am having trouble thinking through what type(s) to use, how to create a range for my dataframe column values (like 1.00 to 2.00)feet......

***or the cop-out would be I manually categorize the plant entries into their appropriate descriptive range, but then I run into a similar issue: I could do something like:

```
if user_height_pref == 'Desk range'
   user_height_pref = [0.25 to 1.00 feet, 0.25 to 0.75 feet, 1.00 to 1.50 feet...]
```

but then how do I search through through my dataframe height column? Unsure of how to search/match elements of this list to my dataframe column (using a similar code as care_df)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with multiple criteria.

```
df1 = df[(df['Feet'] >=0.25) & (df['Feet'] <= 1.0)]
```

You can also check out this post.

[How to select rows in a DataFrame between two values, in Python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617845/how-to-select-rows-in-a-dataframe-between-two-values-in-python-pandas/40442778)

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure if it works with float. Upon running my program, that line creates:     TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'