# How to check if a date (manually passed variable) is between a given startdate and enddate in a pandas dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to pass 2 dates manually to variables and I need to filter a pandas dataframe, where the date values are between the 2 date variables.

The issue I'm facing is, the column in the dataframe is of type 'datetime64[ns]' but the value contains only the date (for eg: yyyy-mm-dd. No time.) and to be able to filter based on the condition, it tried to pass a date manually to a variable by doing the following:

```
start = np.array(np.datetime64('2020-03-01'))
end = np.array(np.datetime64('2020-03-31'))
```

Then, I'm trying to filter the results by doing the following:

```
filter1 = df1['TRANSACTION_DT'] > start
filter2 = df1['TRANSACTION_DT'] < end

df1.where(filter1 & filter2, inplace=True)
```

However, when I'm doing this, I'm getting all nulls. How can I declare datetime64 variables and manually pass a date so that I can filter my dataframe.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows in a DataFrame between two values, in Python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617845/how-to-select-rows-in-a-dataframe-between-two-values-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @RichieV Not exactly. I'm having an issue because I need to manually pass datetime64 value and then compare. The example you mentioned is comparing a value which is an integer. Though the logic is similar, I'm specifically having issue with the datetime64 type variable comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You could use simple clustering along with & clause

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": [datetime(2020,1, 2), datetime(2019, 11, 2), datetime(2018, 1, 2)],
})
df = df[(df['date'] > '2019-10-10') & (df['date'] < '2019-12-01')]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ["2020-01-02", "2019-11-02", "2018-01-02"],
df = df[(df['date'] > '2019-10-10') & (df['date'] < '2019-12-01')]
```

Comment: here you can see that the filtering works seamlessly when the column is of `datetime.datetime` and also when it is a string

Answer (score 1):

This does seem to work. However, the problem is the use of `.where()`. This *replaces* the values in the columns where the condition is not met by `False`. This is not a valid `np.datetime64` value, so it gets replaced by `NaT`, the datetime equivalent of a `nan` value.

If you only want to look at those rows for which the filter is true, you should use:

```
df1.loc[filter1 & filter2]
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

You could try this:

```py
df.loc[df.TRANSACTION_DT.between('2020-07-03', '2020-07-08', inclusive=False)]
```

In a nutshell, you could try any of the following methods. I personally find **Method-2** as the most versatile one. In case you are only interested to find dates between two given dates, you could also use **Method-1** (`pd.Series.between()`).

```py
# import numpy as np
# import pandas as pd

# start = '2020-07-03'
# end = '2020-07-08'

# One line solution with pd.DataFrame.where()
# Method-1
df.where(df.TRANSACTION_DT.between(start, end, inclusive=False))
# Method-2
df.where((df.TRANSACTION_DT > start) & (df.TRANSACTION_DT < end))
# Method-3
df.where(np.logical_and((df.TRANSACTION_DT > start), (df.TRANSACTION_DT < end)))
```

For example, if you use *Method-1*, and only want to see which rows in the dataframe satisfy the filtering condition(s), you could do it as follows:

```py
# Note: I used the DUMMY DATA created 
#       in the following section for df
df.loc[df.TRANSACTION_DT.between(start, end, inclusive=False)]

## Output:
#
#   TRANSACTION_DT  Method_1  Method-2
# 3     2020-07-04      True      True
# 4     2020-07-05      True      True
# 5     2020-07-06      True      True
# 6     2020-07-07      True      True
```

### Example: With *Dummy Data*

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start = '2020-07-03'
end = '2020-07-08'

## Dummy Data
dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-07-01', end='2020-07-10', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['TRANSACTION_DT'])

## Apply Criterion
# Method-1
df['Method_1'] = df.TRANSACTION_DT.between(start, end, inclusive=False)
# Method-2
df['Method_2'] = (df.TRANSACTION_DT > start) & (df.TRANSACTION_DT < end)
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```sh
  TRANSACTION_DT  Method_1  Method_2
0     2020-07-01     False     False
1     2020-07-02     False     False
2     2020-07-03     False     False
3     2020-07-04      True      True
4     2020-07-05      True      True
5     2020-07-06      True      True
6     2020-07-07      True      True
7     2020-07-08     False     False
8     2020-07-09     False     False
9     2020-07-10     False     False
```

Comment: @PKV Does this help?