# How to remove all rows that have a column value higher than the absolute value of 0.10 with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

How do I drop all the rows that have a RET with absolute value greater than 0.10?

Tried using this, not sure what to do

```
df_drop = [data[data[abs(float('RET')) < 0.10]
```

Comment: Please don't post data or code as an image. This is hard to copy'n'past and makes it more difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows in a DataFrame between two values, in Python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617845/how-to-select-rows-in-a-dataframe-between-two-values-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep RET with absolute value greater than 0.10 by

```
data = data[abs(data['RET'].astype('float')) >= 0.10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`abs()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) and [`le()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) or [`lt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) to filter for the wanted values.

```
df_drop = data[data['RET'].abs().lt(0.10)]
```

Also consider [`between()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html). Select a appropriate policy for `inclusive`. It can be "neither", "both", "left" or "right".

```
df_drop = data[data['RET'].between(-0.10, 0.10, inclusive="neither")]
```

### Example

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'RET':[0.011806, -0.122290, 0.274011, 0.039013, -0.05044],
    'other': [1,2,3,4,5]
})

        RET  other
0  0.011806      1
1 -0.122290      2
2  0.274011      3
3  0.039013      4
4 -0.050440      5
```

Both ways aboth will lead to

```
        RET  other
0  0.011806      1
3  0.039013      4
4 -0.050440      5
```

All rows with an absolute value greater than 0.10 in `RET` are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to code it in two steps to figure it out better.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val':[5, 11, 89, 63],
                   'RET':[-0.1, 0.5, -0.04, 0.09],
                   })

# Step 1 : define the mask
m = abs(df['RET']) > 0.1
# Step 2 : apply the mask
df[m]

print(df)
```

**Result**

```
df[m]
   val  RET
1   11  0.5
```